# JS auto compute without submit button

Tags: javascript

i want to auto calculate the 5 textboxes without using a submit button from the value of my main textbox so
1 textbox = (auto computed) 5textbox

**this is the js in my `<head>` tag**

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$('#tb6').keyup(function(){
    var textbox;

        var tb1;
        var tb2;
        var tb3;
        var tb4;
        var tb5;

    textbox = parseInt($('#textbox').val());
    tb1 = parseInt($('#tb1').val());
    tb2 = parseInt($('#tb2').val());
    tb3 = parseInt($('#tb3').val());
    tb4 = parseInt($('#tb4').val());
    tb5 = parseInt($('#tb5').val());


        tb1 =  textbox * 0.10;
        tb2  = textbox * 0.10;
        tb3  = textbox * 0.10;
        tb4  = textbox * 0.50;
        tb5   = tb1+ tb2 + tb3;
    var tb6 = tb4 - tb5;
    $('#tb6').val(tb6.toFixed(2));


});
</script>
</head>
```

**form**

```
        <form>
    <br>input textbox:        <input id = "textbox" type = "text"    name="textbox" required>
    </td>
    </td>
    </table>
    <table>
    <tr><td>
    <br>
    <p id="para">label1</p>
    <br>textbox1:     <input id = "tb1"  type = "text"    name = "tb1" required>
    <br>textbox2:     <input id = "tb2"   type = "text"    name = "tb2"  required>
    <br>textbox3:     <input id = "tb3"   type = "text"    name = "tb3"  required>
    </td>
    <td><br><br><br><br><p id="paraa">label2</p>
    <br>textbox4:     <input id = "tb4"   type = "text"    name = "tb4" readonly>
    <br>textbox5:     <input id = "tb5"    type = "text"    name = "tb5"  readonly>
    // result
    <br>textbox5:     <input id = "tb6"   type = "text"    name = "tb6" readonly>
    </td></tr>
    </form>
```

im new on JS, i dont know whats the problem. how am i able to auto calculate?

thank you guys

https://jsfiddle.net/no619pmu/5/

Comment: What is the **CaIn** ?

Comment: Where the `sss1`,  `pa1`, `ph1`, `in1` `d1` comes from? It does not seems to be initialized...

Comment: What is wrong with the current code?

Comment: @xxxmatko : sorry, edited

Comment: @SatejS : i dont know i didnt work on mine

Comment: @lolka_bolka : sorry, edited

Comment: Add your script to the end of the body element.

Comment: @debin not showing on other textbox's

Comment: first tb1-tb5 is useless. bcoz you assign them again. also your html is wrong there are unnecessary closing tag after first input

Comment: what you have to show in other textbox?

Comment: can you update the html .In some case td ,tr and table tag is not in order

Comment: @xxxmatko Thank you sir its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you have written readonly in `tb6` and keyup on same input which can not be possible
Do
`$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {` if you want auto compute on input text..
As per you code I modified in jquery

```js
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
  var textbox = parseInt($('#textbox').val());
  var tb1 = parseInt($('#tb1').val());
  var tb2 = parseInt($('#tb2').val());
  var tb3 = parseInt($('#tb3').val());
  var tb4 = parseInt($('#tb4').val());
  var tb5 = parseInt($('#tb5').val());

  tb1 = textbox * 0.10;
  tb2 = textbox * 0.10;
  tb3 = textbox * 0.10;
  tb4 = textbox * 0.50;
  tb5 = tb1 + tb2 + tb3;

  var tb6 = tb4 - tb5;
  $('#tb6').val(tb6.toFixed(2));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <br>input textbox:
  <input id="textbox" type="text" name="textbox" required>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <br>
        <p id="para">label1</p>
        <br>textbox1:
        <input id="tb1" type="text" name="tb1" required>
        <br>textbox2:
        <input id="tb2" type="text" name="tb2" required>
        <br>textbox3:
        <input id="tb3" type="text" name="tb3" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p id="paraa">label2</p>
        <br>textbox4:
        <input id="tb4" type="text" name="tb4" readonly>
        <br>textbox5:
        <input id="tb5" type="text" name="tb5" readonly>
        // result 
        <br>textbox5:
        <input id="tb6" type="text" name="tb6" readonly>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

//As you didnot mentioned what will be in other textboxes..

Answer (score 0):

when do

```
$('#tb6').keyup(function(){})
```

the `tb6` input is not render

Comment: how? this is my first time writing a js

Comment: Browser from top to bottom read code, but when it read $('#tb6').keyup it don't know what's tb6?so put $('#tb6').keyup(function(){ this function on html in the end